# Getting permission denied even though it is added

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-sdcard

I want to write to a file on the sd card, I added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`, however when I try it, I dont get any errors in the virtual device, but in LogCat I get the following

```
12-05 13:09:08.743: E/XMLWriter(367): Permission denied
12-05 13:09:08.753: E/XMLWriter(367): /mnt/sdcard/alzheimer/appointments.xml (Permission denied)
```

Even though it was working before, now I can't get it to work.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Add your logcat error.

Comment: are you running this in an emulator?if yes does it have an sdcard?

Comment: @insomniac I checked the virtual device settings, it seems I didn't specify a space of the sd card, I added some space and will try it now

Comment: @insomniac it worked, turns out it was for the lack of sd card space in the virtual device

Comment: @aizen92 If you can write up specifically what the problem was (and how to recreate and fix it), I suggest posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I did not specify the amount of space for my virtual device's sd card. I just added some space and it worked.